# Error handling of non-HTTP errors using `error_handler` in flask

Tags: flask

I want to convert non-HTTP erros occuring in a flask api to HTTP errors using flask's error handler.

Intended flow:

- non-HTTP error occurs, gets thrown
- gets caught in the error handler of the corresponding non-HTTP error
- the error handler method converts the non-HTTP error to an HTTP error, gets thrown
- gets caught in the corresponding HTTP error handler
- error is handled and response generated and sent

For ex: FileNotFound is raised, it is converted to a 500 and then handled by the InternalServerError.
Here, the FileNotFound and InternalServerError both are registered error handlers.

Also, I do not intend to use `abort`, as with `abort` each error occurence individually needs to be handled.

Tried

```py
def handle_non_http_error(error):
    raise HTTPError

def handle_http_error(error):
    # response generation and reply
```

The above responds with the `HTTPError` handled by flask not with the defined `http_error`.

The `handle_http_error` works fine with a http error. So, the connection between two error handlers is not working.